# Когда стоит использовать OAuth2

Tags: авторизация, oauth2

Когда стоит использовать OAuth2 и для чего он годится? 
Все мануалы не вносят ясности. Нужно поднять приложение с авторизацией решил использовать что-то новое для себя (OAuth2), но не могу понять подходит ли он мне. Мне нужна авторизация без всяких привязок к сторонним сервисам (facebook, vk), отлично бы подошла авторизация с JWT. Во всех источниках пишут что необходим некий провайдер для поставки токенов, а если мне ненужны эти провайдеры как быть?